# Code being skipped over when Firestore value inserted into notifier provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to insert a newly created Firestore document id into a notifier provider.

I create a new document and get the document id of the newly created document. I can then insert that document id into my trxnNotifierProvider. I will then save all the data contained in the trxnNotifierProvider to a Firestore document.

The document id I get is a client id. I use this document id to link the client to the trxn document.

I have a Trxn screen where I can enter the client data and trxn data. When I save the data, I save the client data first to a separate document by creating a new client document and I get the document id and insert it into the trxnNotifierProvider.clientId field. This part all takes place in the client provider class.

After I save the client data then execution is returned to the Trxn screen and the trxn data is saved by creating a new trxn document. This save is executed in the trxn provider class.

**My problem:**
When I insert the new client document id into the trxnNotifierProvider the execution is not returned back to the same place in the code in the trxn screen where it will next save the trxn data.

If I don't save the client document id to the trxnNotifierProvider then execution occurs as I would expect but I don't have the new client document id.

How do I get the new client document id and insert it into the trxn provider so I can save it as part of the trxn data and link the client to the trxn? Am I doing it wrong by performing this action in the client provider class?

During the execution, there is not error thrown but the execution just goes to rebuilding the widget tree and the screen.

I hope this makes sense.

Here is the process I am talking about:

```
Trxn Screen initiates the save process
                      try {
                        if (ref.read(clientNotifierProvider).clientId == null ||
                            ref.read(clientNotifierProvider).clientId == "") {
                          ref.read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier).saveClient(
                              ref.read(clientNotifierProvider),
                              widget.isNewClient); <<< LAST LINE EXECUTED IF CLIENT DOCUMENT ID SAVED TO TRXN PROVIDER
                        } else {
                          ref.read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier).saveClient(
                              ref.read(clientNotifierProvider), false);
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        print('Trxn Detail  $e');
                      }

                      populateTrxnProvider();

                      // Save Trxn to Firestore
                      ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier).saveTrxn(
                          ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider),
                          ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId!,
                          widget.newTrxn!);
```

This is the code inside the client provider class where I save the client data to Firestore:

```
saveClient(client, isNewClient, [clientId]) async {
    if (isNewClient == true) {
      final newClient = Client(
        fName: client.fName,
        lName: client.lName,
        address1: client.address1,
        address2: client.address2,
        city: client.city,
        clientState: client.clientState,
        zipCode: client.zipCode,
        cellPhone: client.cellPhone,
        homePhone: client.homePhone,
        email: client.email,
        userCompanyId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId,
        userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId,
        clientId: client.clientId,
      );

      try {
        DocumentReference? newDocRef =
            await firestoreService.saveNewClient(toMap(newClient));
        //ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier).updateClientId(newDocRef!.id);  <<<< THIS IS THE LINE THAT CAUSES PROBLEM
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }

    } else {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentClientProfile =
          await clientDB.doc(client.ClientId).get();

      var newClient = Client(
          fName: (state.fName != null && state.fName != "")
              ? state.fName
              : currentClientProfile.get('fName'),
          lName: (state.lName != null && state.lName != "")
              ? state.lName
              : currentClientProfile.get('lName'),
          address1: (state.address1 != null && state.address1 != "")
              ? state.address1
              : currentClientProfile.get('address1'),
          address2: (state.address2 != null && state.address2 != "")
              ? state.address2
              : currentClientProfile.get('address2'),
          city: (state.city != null && state.city != "")
              ? state.city
              : currentClientProfile.get('city'),
          clientState: (clientState != null && clientState != "")
              ? clientState
              : currentClientProfile.get('clientState'),
          zipCode: (state.zipCode != null && state.zipCode != "")
              ? state.zipCode
              : currentClientProfile.get('zipCode'),
          cellPhone: (state.cellPhone != null && state.cellPhone != "")
              ? state.cellPhone
              : currentClientProfile.get('cellPhone'),
          userCompanyId:
              (state.userCompanyId != null && state.userCompanyId != "")
                  ? state.userCompanyId
                  : currentClientProfile.get('userCompanyId'),
          userId: (state.userId != null && state.userId != "")
              ? state.userId
              : currentClientProfile.get('userId'),
          clientId: (state.clientId != null && state.clientId != "")
              ? state.clientId
              : currentClientProfile.get('clientId'),
          homePhone: (state.homePhone != null && state.homePhone != "")
              ? state.homePhone
              : currentClientProfile.get('homePhone'));

      firestoreService.saveClient(newClient, clientId);
    }
```